# how to create such an int array that increase by one from the last to the first element

Tags: php

how to achieve the same array down bellow with php i have that code

```
<?php

$a = 9; // number of arrays
$b = 3; // number of elements inside array
$c = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < $a; $i++)
{
    $d = [];
    
    for ($j = 0; $j < $b; $j++)
    {
        $d[] = $i = 0;
    }
    
    $c[] = $d;
}

print_r($c);
?>


[

[0,0,0],
[0,0,1],
[0,1,1],
[1,1,1],
[1,1,2],
[1,2,2],
[2,2,2],
[2,2,3],
[2,3,3],
[3,3,3]
]
```

i tried alot of mathematic ways with no success can you please help me

Comment: So you want $d[] = $i?

Comment: What ways have you tried?

Comment: `giving 9 columns and 3 rows`...the array in your question has 3 columns and 9 rows

Comment: yes im sorry i mean 3 columns and 9 rows

i have tried multiple calculations

Comment: that's the array i want by only giving 3 is number of columns and 9 number for rows

[
[0,0,0],
[0,0,1],
[0,1,1],
[1,1,1],
[1,1,2],
[1,2,2],
[2,2,2],
[2,2,3],
[2,3,3],
[3,3,3],
]

Comment: You have 10 rows.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get your result with this code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $data[] = [intdiv($i, 3), 
               intdiv($i + 1, 3), 
               intdiv($i + 2, 3)];
}

var_export($data);
```

See: https://3v4l.org/NChUj

Comment: bro u saved my life <3